# Magento 2, how to get a widget to update immediately?

Tags: magento-2.1, widgets

So I've created a widget, and I noticed that the products were not updating as frequently as I wanted. So I re-created the widget within the same block. However, even after re-indexing, and re-processing my entire cache, the modified Widget doesn't actually display anything until, what seems to be 24 hours after modification.

I cannot figure out why.